# How to prevent outside CSS from adding and overriding ReactJS component styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components

I have a custom ReactJS component that I want to style in a certain way and provide as a plugin to many different web sites. But when web sites use global styles (Twitter bootstrap or another css framework) it adds and overrides styles of my component. For example:

global.css:

```
    label { 
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
     }
```

component.js:

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
      let style = {
          color: "green"
      };
    return (<label style={style}>Hello</label>);
  }
}
```

result:

[image]

**Above I didn't use "font-weight: bold" in my component's style but in result my component is using it.**

I'd like to be able to encapsulate **my custom components's styles in a way that makes them look the same across all the web sites**.

Comment: As far as I know if you don't want your element to inherit properties you're going to need to set them yourself. For example style = { color: "green" , fontWeight: "normal"}

Comment: If you use a css framework components will get that frameworks styling. Remove those component styles from the framework you are using

Comment: @Paran0a I can't foresee which properties will be in global.css or I don't know which css framework will be on a web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach in my view is to define some kind of reset class for your component and put in a set of css resets you can find out there
(e.g. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

The definition in a `sass` file could look like this:

```
.your-component-reset {
    div, span, object, iframe {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    // add some more reset styles
}
```

To avoid writing a lot when you don't want to use `sass` just use the universal selector `*`:

```
.your-component-reset * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-weight: normal;
     // other reset styles ...
}
```