# How to exclude global styles in a React App?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I am using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) for building my React Project.

However there is a component which has to be embedded to a different site. Meaning, I am providing the production build of this component to embed it to a different site.

My **React app's css** is getting overridden by the **global styles** defined in that website.

I don't want this behaviour. Is there any way I can isolate the css of my react app and the global css of the other website.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409233/how-to-prevent-outside-css-from-adding-and-overriding-reactjs-component-styles) but the solutions didn't help me.

Comment: *"However there is a component which has to be embedded to a different site."* Can you please explain this a bit better?

Comment: Let me know if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If iframes and Web Components are out of the question, the only remaining option is CSS resets.

Create a CSS class and a series of rules that reset the styles of any elements that occur inside that class.

```
.my-reset {
  /* Global resets (e.g. font family) */
}

.my-reset p {
  /* Reset paragraph styles */
}

.my-reset label {
  /* Reset label styles */
}

/* etc. */
```

Apply that class to the root-level component:

```
function MyApp() {
    <div className="my-reset">
        { /* app goes here */ }
    </div>
}
```

There are plenty of CSS reset libraries out there. Since you have no control over global styles, you're going to have to be heavy handed with the resets. So if it's at all possible, make your component embeddable as an iframe.

Comment: I tried CSS reset but haven't been successful so far, can you recomment me any library which works well with react? Or a library for embedding in iframe?

Comment: I was using Material UI for the react frontend, I added CssBaseline which basically does css reset. Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple solutions to this problem

1. Use `!important` in those styles possible.
2. Use `id` to give styling instead of `class`, as `id` has higher presidence.
3. If you give more specific styling to the elements then the build file css will override the outer site's css, i.e like if we write our css like `.parent#child` this is more specific styling and it will override the wrapper site's css.

Check this out https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: I don't have any control over the other website's css, to I can't change their css, for eg. they have a style for button which gets applied to my button, but I don't want that to happen.

Comment: yeah you need to give this styling to your codebase only not to others, these changes are for your code not there...

Comment: Yes it sounds good but I think css reset is much better approach, as I don't have to change each style. :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

There's another sort of scrappy solution that you could use in the case where you don't need the old table style and the new Material-UI tables on the same HTML page.

If you own the site that you are trying to embed the React app in (i.e., you have control over the new environment's CSS), another thing you could do to reset the CSS styles for the components in your app is to remove the classes that are overwriting your styles.

For example, if you're using Material-UI tables and your existing table styles are affecting the render, you could put the existing table styles into a separate CSS file that you only import when you render your existing tables, on another HTML page.