# Overriding material ui TextFields by other part of web page application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have frontEnd application which I have written in React and Material-Ui libraries. I have injected this application to the shop web page. There are conflicts with styles because shops styles override styles from Material-Ui. For example Text fields in modal Dialog should look like below(alone React app):

[image]

The problem is when it is injected to the shop web page, then this modal window looks like:

[image]

Probably there is a problem with overriding shop styles for inputs. I mean:

```
form input[type="text"], form input[type="password"], form input[type="date"], form input[type="number"], form input[type="email"], form input[type="search"] .uneditable-input, form textarea, select {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #c2c2c2;
    border-width: 1px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
```

My implemenation form from modal windows in React is:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Formik } from "formik"
import * as EmailValidator from "email-validator"
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
const ValidatedForm = ({ submit }) => {
    let isSubmited = false;
    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={{ email: "", phone: "" }}
            onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                isSubmited = true;
                console.log("Submitting")
                console.log(values)
                setSubmitting(false)
                submit(values);
            }}
            validate={values => {
                let errors = {};
                if (!values.email && !values.phone) {
                    errors.noData = "Uzupełnij przynajmniej jedno poniższych z pól poprawnie"
                    return errors
                }
                if (values.email) {
                    if (!EmailValidator.validate(values.email)) {
                        errors.email = "Wprowadź poprawny adres email"
                    }
                }
                if (values.phone) {
                    const phoneRegex = /^\+48[0-9]{9}$/
                    if (!phoneRegex.test(values.phone)) {
                        errors.phone = "Podaj numer w formacie +48xxxxxxxxx"
                    }
                }
                return errors
            }}
        >
            {props => {
                const {
                    values,
                    touched,
                    errors,
                    isSubmitting,
                    handleChange,
                    handleSubmit,
                } = props;
                return (

                    <form style={{ marginTop: 30 }} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {isSubmited && errors.noData && (
                            <div  style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors.noData}</div>
                        )}
                        <TextField
                            margin="dense"
                            name="email"
                            id="email_input"
                            label="email"
                            type="text"
                            fullWidth
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.email}
                            error={errors.email && touched.email}
                        />
                        {isSubmited && errors.email && touched.email && (
                            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors.email}</div>
                        )}
                        <TextField
                            margin="dense"
                            id="phone_input"
                            label="telefon"
                            name="phone"
                            type="text"
                            fullWidth
                            value={values.phone}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            error={errors.phone && touched.phone}
                        />
                        {isSubmited && errors.phone && touched.phone && (
                            <div className="input-feedback" style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors.phone}</div>
                        )}
                        <Button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting} color="primary" variant="contained"
                            style={{ marginTop: 20 }} onClick={() => { isSubmited = true }}>Wyślij
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                );
            }}
        </Formik>
    )
}
export default ValidatedForm
```

Maybe should I in some way add !important property in React app? But how? The problem I have access only to React application. As we can see on the above picture tehre are styles:
I would be greateful for help.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636729/how-to-exclude-global-styles-in-a-react-app

Comment: it's more like different media queries break points - mobile applied (earlier) on higher screen width than in your env