# How to prevent css from being applied to any block inside html?

Tags: html, css, frameworks

For example: there is html, a framework (materialize, js and css) and a plugin for displaying a table (tabulator, js and css) are connected to it. The html has a div where the table is rendered using the tabulator plugin, with all sorts of select input filters. Materialize interferes with this table and changes the styles of the table's inputs. How can I prevent Materializ from processing this div?

I wanted the styles with materialize not to interfere with the styles of the tabulator plugin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636729/how-to-exclude-global-styles-in-a-react-app